# Solving a differential equation using substitution - steps verification

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:

$y'=\cos(y-x)$ , where $y'$ is the derivative of y.

My steps are:

Substitution: $y-x=t$
$$
\begin{align}
(t+x)'&=\cos(t)\\ 
t'+1 &= \cos(t) \\
\frac{1}{\cos(t)-1}*t'&=1 \\
\int \frac{1}{\cos(t)-1}dt&=\int dy \\
\end{align}
$$
Are my steps so far correct? I'm still learning DE.. If not, could you correct me and point me to the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me except last line you should have x instead of y $\int \frac{1}{cos(t)-1}dt=\int dx$. Because $t'=\frac {dt}{dx}$

Comment: @Aryadeva Thanks. So now I just compute the integrals, return to my substitution and isolate y?

Comment: Exactly Petra...Evaluate both integrals then unsubstitute $t=y-x$ and isolate $y$ .For your attempt  (+1)